# Mysql-Using between in a DateTime field is showing error

Tags: java, mysql, datetime

My query is:

```
select count(NewCrgs.Water.id) as student, 
count(distinct NewCrgs.Water.school_id) as school,      
sum(NewCrgs.Water.num_waterSource) as total, 
sum(NewCrgs.Water.activeWaterSource) as active, 
sum(NewCrgs.Water.is_potable) as potable,  
sum(NewCrgs.Water.is_informed_authority_water_prob) as isInformed 

from NewCrgs.Water 
Where NewCrgs.Water.created_at between cast( Wed Feb 01 11:29:41 BDT 2017 as DateTime) 
and cast( Tue Feb 28 11:29:41 BDT 2017  as DateTime)  and NewCrgs.Water.res_type = 1
```

but it shows error in date field, where is the error ???

Comment: Maybe it's because you forgot to wrap the date-string with single quotes ? (e.g. `SELECT CAST('2014-02-28 08:14:57' AS DATETIME);`)

Comment: ( 'Tue Feb 28 11:29:41 BDT 2017 ' as DateTime)